# Cell Statistics in ArcMap not working properly

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-analyst, cell-statistics

I just want to use the Cell Statistics tool to sum the value of 8 different raster layers. The problem is that the output always just includes a part of the input rasters, no matter what i change.The area with the black triangle is what i get and as you can see there is much more cells that should be calculated.

[image]

Comment: Extents of you rasters are different. You need expand all of them to a largest one.

Comment: Alright, can you tell me a way how to do that?

Comment: Go to environment and set extent, cell size and snap raster to biggie. Use raster calculator to expand others. Simply type "raster1". Continue with all of them. This will fill voids with nodata cells. Perform statistics on expanded versions.

Comment: @FelixIP Any chance we could see your excellent comments as an answer?